# Using a grep -E command to find 3 different words content in a string

Tags: linux

Using a grep -E command to find these words content in a Dictionary(file) "ice" then an "s" or a "d" i.e. ices or iced using a square brackets. Thanks!

Comment: As this is phrased it is not a question. Please edit this post into a question and make it more clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
grep 'ice[s|d]' dictionary_file.txt
```

As in the following example:

```
mtak@frisbee:~$ more dict.txt
icecube
ices
icea
iceb
iced
mtak@frisbee:~$ grep 'ice[s|d]' dict.txt 
ices
iced
mtak@frisbee:~$
```

Comment: Thanks you so much I did this one but is without brackets grep 'ices\|iced' dict/words